# Get Install Location in Wix and write in Registry

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I have following Wix File that installs the file in **Program Files(x86)** for 64 bit system and **Program Files** in 32 bit system. In the program I need to access the file **lpa.config** that is present in Installed folder, which may be one of two above. For This I need to write the Installed folder in Registry. Is there any way to get the Installed folder location in Wix?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="CustomWixInstallerWithCustomAction" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="LogPoint" UpgradeCode="ba9015b9-027f-4451-adb2-e38f9168a850">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="no" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="CustomWixInstallerWithCustomAction" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="CustomWixInstaller" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="SomeRandomEXE">
        <File Source ="G:\SarVaGYa\myworkspace\LatestLpa\lpa\lpa_c\here\src\lpa\Release\lpa.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="registry_values" Guid="{11FB6C4C-3C90-4F46-B0D2-BB95150F60E6}">
        <RegistryValue
             KeyPath="yes"
             Root="HKCU"
             Key="Software\Logpoint"
             Value="Here I need the path"
             Type="string" />
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, starting from WiX documentation example:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName"
              Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="SetupPath" Value="PUT-PATH-HERE"/>
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

WiX is based on Windows Installer and Registry values are [Formatted properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609.aspx), you can use familiar syntax to access properties:

```
<RegistryValue Type="string" Name="SetupPath" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"/>
```

Property name matches your `<Directory>` element ID, in your case: `<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER"`. 
There are other ways to do it but...well IMO this is easiest one.

Comment: Writing INSTALLLOCATION in Registry is giving blank string.

Comment: @SarvagyaPant sorry, you're using INSTALLFOLDER.

Comment: You can use your IDs, standard [MSI properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and properties generated during installation. I'd suggest to use verbose log for msiexec and you'll see them all!